# Are there any other minigames besides Funky Bus?

Tags: disco-zoo

Tapping on the yellow bus in the zoo parking lot will activate a Flappy Bird-style minigame called Funky Bus.  Are there any other hidden minigames in Disco Zoo?

Answer (score 1):

If you get all the statues maxed out you can play the same mini game but with gravity reversed (and a rainbow bus).

Answer (score 0):

At the construction site, tapping the upper left Porta-Potty activates a galaga style minigame

Comment: I see the potties, but nothing happens when I tap on it. It is also very close to the "Total number of animals" or "Coins per minute" thingy, which pop-ups the statistics page :/